# Estamos recompensando a los autores de preguntas

Tags: discusión, reputación, artículo

<sub>Esta pregunta es una traducción de la publicación en el blog [We’re Rewarding the Question Askers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) hecha por [Sara Chipps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/139284/sara-chipps) (Directora de Public Q&A de Stack Overflow) anunciando el cambio en la reputación recibida por los votos positivos en las preguntas</sub>

---

En mi [primer artículo en el blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/18/building-community-inclusivity-stack-overflow/), escribí sobre lo que una experiencia personal me enseñó sobre la comunidad de Stack Overflow. Dije que íbamos a dar un paso atrás y reevaluar la forma en que proporcionamos retroalimentación, cómo podemos mejorar la calidad del contenido y cómo podemos reducir la fricción entre las personas. Dije que nuestra meta es que el proceso de hacer preguntas sea indoloro y beneficioso tanto para las personas nuevas como para los veteranos de Stack Overflow.

Durante este período de reevaluación, notamos algo en nuestro sistema de recompensas de reputación. Damos diez puntos de reputación adicionales a cualquiera que reciba un voto positivo en una respuesta, pero sólo damos cinco puntos de reputación a las personas que reciban un voto positivo en una pregunta.

Aquí está la historia: Cuando Stack Overflow se lanzó en 2008, dimos los mismos puntos a los votos positivos en las respuestas y preguntas. Tres años más tarde, se tomó la decisión de devaluar la reputación de los votantes en las preguntas. La idea era que este cambio animaría a la gente a centrarse en proporcionar respuestas de buena calidad en lugar de hacer preguntas.

Podemos mirar hacia atrás sobre esta decisión con el beneficio de la retrospectiva. Esta decisión puede haber sido la correcta en ese momento con la información que teníamos en ese momento, pero hemos visto los efectos que ha tenido en nuestra comunidad. Recompensamos a las personas que dan respuestas a un ritmo más alto que a las que hacen preguntas.

Como miembro de la comunidad de Stack Overflow desde hace mucho tiempo, sé, como muchos de vosotros, que publicar una buena pregunta es difícil! Requiere consideración y una atención a la mejor manera de transmitir el problema que estás teniendo. Necesitas dar un paso atrás y pretender que estás describiendo tu problema a un extraño total que no tiene contexto alrededor de tu situación. No están viendo tus logs de compilación, y no saben qué característica estás creando, qué bibliotecas estás usando, o qué versión de framework está en tu equipo.

También hay que ser consciente de que hay mucha información que es extraña. Necesitas saber qué partes del mensaje de error incluir y qué partes son exclusivas de tu máquina. Necesitas incluir los pasos que has dado hasta ahora y el resultado de tus pruebas. En resumen, necesitas ser un experto en hacer preguntas para asegurarte de que vas a obtener la mejor respuesta. Eso requiere habilidad y experiencia, es valioso y es algo que queremos celebrar.

A partir de hoy, lo estamos deshaciendo. Estamos cambiando la reputación ganada al obtener una pregunta con voto positivo a diez puntos, haciéndola igual a la reputación ganada de un voto positivo a una respuesta.

Estamos recalculando la reputación de cada individuo de Stack Overflow y Stack Exchange basándonos en este cambio. Cada pregunta ganada en el pasado ganará un valor de diez puntos de reputación retroactivamente.

En Stack Overflow, esperamos que unos 2,4 millones de personas ganen más reputación. Este cambio va más allá de la reputación; queremos que envíe un mensaje claro: celebramos a los que hacen las preguntas. ¡HURRA POR LOS QUE PREGUNTAN!

Para aquellos de vosotros que estáis obteniendo nuevos privilegios: os pedimos que asumáis la responsabilidad con reverencia. Sois los expertos en preguntas. Sois las personas que pueden identificar una pregunta con la que estáis luchando y saben lo difícil que puede ser estar al otro lado de ese teclado. Gracias de antemano por asesorar gentilmente a los que hacen preguntas a través de vuestra experiencia.

Creemos que tanto los que preguntan como los que responden son una parte vital de nuestro ecosistema. Agradecemos lo mucho que han hecho para que este sea el sitio más grande de preguntas y respuestas técnicas de la historia, y queremos agradecerles por cada contribución desde el origen del sitio.

Estamos haciendo más.

Hemos implementado una experiencia mejorada de hacer preguntas a través de Stack Overflow (los sitios de Stack Exchange lo obtendrán en el primer trimestre del año próximo). Meg Risdal [anticipó las mejoras](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/08/20/upcoming-on-stack-overflow/) en agosto y Lisa Park proporcionó [una mirada entre bastidores](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/26/research-update-improving-the-question-asking-experience/) a la investigación que se llevó a cabo para desarrollar las mejoras en septiembre. No podríamos estar más contentos de poder ofrecer esto a todo el mundo!

Ayer, Julia Silge [publicó un resumen](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/12/research-update-a-b-testing-the-new-question-form) de los resultados de nuestra prueba A/B sobre la nueva experiencia. Vimos un *aumento significativo* en el número de personas que empezaron y enviaron una pregunta. También nos fijamos en la calidad de las preguntas porque queríamos asegurarnos de que estábamos ayudando a todas las personas a escribir las preguntas que probablemente iban a ser contestadas. No vimos ninguna disminución en la calidad de la pregunta.

Para llevar: los cambios que hemos hecho están aumentando el número de preguntas que se publican en Stack Overflow, sin disminuir la calidad. Más preguntas de alta calidad; esta es la comunidad donde todos pueden prosperar.

Lo he dicho antes y lo diré de nuevo: yo misma y el equipo de la comunidad estamos muy entusiasmados por mejorar la experiencia que todos los niveles de programadores tienen en Stack Overflow, desde los nuevos usuarios que están aprendiendo por primera vez hasta nuestros respetados moderadores que han estado programando durante más de 20 años. Estos cambios, que aumentan los puntos de reputación para los votos positivos de las preguntas y la experiencia mejorada de hacer preguntas, junto con algunos nuevos mecanismos de retroalimentación que anunciaremos la semana que viene, son un emocionante comienzo para trabajar mano a mano con la comunidad para construir un mejor Stack Overflow.

Comment: Como siempre, esta traducción está abierta a mejoras, simplemente editadla si veis algo raro o mal traducido.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo con este cambio (pese a que me ha catapultado por encima de los 30k). Ayudar es más valioso que pedir ayuda, ofrecer conocimiento es más valioso que pedirlo. Poner al mismo nivel dar que recibir reduce el incentivo de dar.

Comment: mi voto positivo es por el trabajo de traducción de @Pikho, yo tampoco estoy para nada de acuerdo con esa decisión y por lo que sé muchos mods y usuarios tampoco pero SE ha dejado de escuchar a la gente y ha tomado un camino supongo que con una visión más empresarial o no sé, creo que la están cagando.

Comment: No creo que sea bueno modificar el baremo a estas alturas (y ya entiendo como pase de 4 a 5k en una noche sin motivo aparente). Estoy de acuerdo con que plantear buenas preguntas requiere cierta experiencia... pero podría darse el caso de que usuarios con experiencia como programadores que dediquen tiempo y esfuerzo en ayudar a otros y planteen pocas preguntas se vean perjudicados en cuanto a su reputación relativa con respecto a otros usuarios menos experimentados que soliciten ayuda con frecuencia.

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que puede ser beneficioso en esta comunidad, ya que los usuarios experimentados pueden intentar crear mas preguntas, que servirán teóricamente a los nuevos a ver como se **debe preguntar**, ademas del contenido nuevo que habría ya que sin duda van a existir buenas respuestas

---

PD: Deberíamos organizar un Preguntaton o algo asi ;)

Comment: Eso que comentas ya existía antes del cambio: Crear una Wiki de comunidad, así que el cambio no aporta absolutamente ningún cambio beneficioso respecto al estado anterior.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster de acuerdo contigo, tal vez si le iban a dar más valor a las preguntas, entonces en consecuencia lo mismo debió de ocurrir con las respuestas

Comment: @Aprendiz La motivación tras el cambio (aparentemente) es incentivar a los usuarios a hacer preguntas de calidad… pero subir la reputación de las preguntas no es ninguna garantía de que las preguntas que vayan a hacerse sean de calidad. En mi aso ahora me lo pienso mucho más antes de votar positivamente una pregunta.

Answer (score -4):

A mi parecer hace falta una característica para proponer un texto de pregunta, poder sugerir corregirla en base al contenido del post, y en caso de ya existir sería más fácil descartarla

Comment: No termino de entender lo que propones

Comment: Por decir una cosa, yo redacto bien el tema que intento resolver, pero mi pregunta no es clara ni precisa, y en automático me empiezan a "votar -1" (como en ésta ocasión), y yo sigo necesitando la ayuda, el objetivo de esta red es apoyar; y a veces la gente que trabajamos para sistemas carecemos de la habilidad de explicarnos claramente. Prongo que exista la característica que te permita redactar un comentario de propuesta de título para la publicación

Comment: perdon, pero no se te entiende.