# Frecuentemos un poco más la cola de votos de cierre

Tags: discusión, colas-de-revisión, votos-de-cierre

Mirando el [historial de revisiones en la cola de votos de cierre](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/close/history) (visible para usuarios con reputación de 10 K o más) observo que en los últimos tres días (desde el 24 de noviembre) apenas cuatro usuarios hemos revisando esta cola. En particular, la última revisión se hizo hace casi 24 horas. Por contra, [la cola](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/close) tiene ahora mismo 166 preguntas.

Los números no son especialmente malos, en comparación con los otros SOxx que siempre tienen números mas altos (ahora mismo SO tiene 8K, SOja apenas un par, SOru 500 y SOpt una treintena). Sin embargo, me da la sensación de que el número va aumentando lenta pero constantemente.

El privilegio de [Emitir votos para cerrar y reabrir](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) se consigue con 3000 puntos y actualmente [hay 113 usuarios con esa reputación o más](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/637/alltime/es-stackoverflow/2015-12-01/83#83).

Entiendo que hay gente que vota para cerrar directamente en las preguntas, sin acceder a través de la cola de revisiones. Así y todo, parece que las preguntas tardan bastante en cerrarse. Y eso que los números han mejorado en la última semana, probablemente porque más usuarios pueden revisar al haberse aumentado la reputación global al [convertir los antiguos +5 a preguntas a +10](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4438/83).

En efecto, sacando números [a partir de consultas de Mariano](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2145/83) tenemos que:

- [Se tarda una media de 7 días (10 000 minutos) en cerrar una pregunta](https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/809043/revisiones-medias-semanales-cantidad-por-dia-y-demora-review-queues-per-week?CantMeses=12&VerPrimeras=0&VerDemoraPrimeras=0&VerEdiciones=0&VerDemoraEdiciones=0&VerCierre=1&VerDemoraCierre=1&VerBajaCalidad=0&VerDemoraBajaCalidad=0&VerTardias=0&VerDemoraTardias=0&VerReapertura=0&VerDemoraReapertura=0#graph), y eso que en septiembre y octubre se bajó hasta el dato de apenas un día.
- [Hay una media de 10 tareas de revisión en la cola de votos de cierre](https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/681999/colas-de-revision-por-semana-en-stack-overflow-en-espanol-review-queues-by-week?CantMeses=6&VerPrimeras=0&VerEdiciones=0&VerCierre=1&VerBajaCalidad=0&VerTardias=0&VerReapertura=0#graph). Venimos de números más bajos, pero sigue siendo poco.

Esto claramente repercute en nuestra [métrica de preguntas respondidas](https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#percentanswered), pues muchas malas preguntas languidecen con una serie de votos de cierre, pero sin estar cerradas del todo, ni tampoco contestadas. En este aspecto estamos bastante peor que otros SOxx.

Por todo ello: ¿os animáis a frecuentar la cola de votos de cierre? Con un par de minutos diarios haréis una gran diferencia.

Comment: esto sera por el efecto monica?

Comment: @JackNavaRow en parte es posible que haya influido. Pero creo que nunca hemos destacado por la revisión de colas, y ya que estamos tampoco en votacion. Gracias fedorqui por lanzar un recordatorio sobre el particular.

Comment: @JackNavaRow por curiosidad: ¿por qué lo decidiste?

Comment: Al ver un número tan alto le tenía pavor, ahí voy en camino.

Comment: Stackoverflow no se merece los moderadores ni la comunidad que tiene la verdad. Viendo lo que hane cho con Monica...

Comment: por mi primer comentario @fedorqui

Comment: @JackNavaRow Disculpen la ignorancia pero qué le hicieron a Monica exactamente, ¿De qué me perdí?

Comment: @ArtEze Te recomiendo revisar meta-stackexchange, puedes iniciar revisando el siguiente post https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335373/what-did-monica-do-to-violate-the-coc

Comment: @eyllanesc Es interesante, de todos modos en mi opinión el sitio es de ellos y pueden hacer lo que quieren, hasta podrían falsear comentarios para hacer que parezca que hizo algo malo. No digo que lo hacen pero es un caso extremo que podría pasar. Así como le removieron el diamante algún día lo pueden volver a poner. Con respecto a la cola de revisiones, el hecho que puedan quitar el moderador no significa que no puedan seguir revisando publicaciones, así que el posible miedo no debe ser tan grande.

Comment: @ArtEze parece que no has revisado todas las publicaciones enlazadas. Por otro lado este sitio no es grande por solo la empresa sino por la comunidad asi que no pueden tomar cualquier decisión sin una reacción por parte de la comunidad, y uno de los efectos de la reacción es que muchos moderadores renunciaron a su cargo(creo que algunos de SOes tambien lo hicieron), otros usuarios muy valiosos dejaron el sitio o limitaron sus acciones haciendo que el sitio pierda su valiosa contribución.

Comment: @ArtEze En este post hay un seguimiento de lo que te señalo: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4364/echando-mods-y-relicencia-forzada-est%c3%a1-todav%c3%ada-stack-exchange-interesada-en-co

Comment: @eyllanesc Gracias, ya entiendo un poco mejor la situación, no estaba ni enterado.

Comment: En lo personal, no poseo aún la reputación para apoyar. Pero después del caso de Mónica, pocas ganas tengo de colaborar con el sitio, aún sigo frecuentando los sitios de stack exchange pero a modo de consulta. Quizá algo similar sucede con otros usuarios que si tienen la reputación.

Comment: Sin darme cuenta, las colas de revisión me estresaban, pero también me apasionaban. Luego, me aburrí de las colas de revisión y las abandoné. Así que decidí revisar solamente las preguntas que pasan mi filtro personalizado. Quiza otros hacen lo mismo. Respuesta: prefiero no darle ni un poco de tiempo a las colas de revisión en general, pero si revisar unas pocas preguntas que me llegan.

Comment: Revisar colas es un trabajo, y me niego a trabajar gratis para Prosus (actuales dueños del sitio). El día en que sea una actividad remunerada, podría optar a ello. Dato: SO fue adquirido por US$1.800 millones de dólares. A los que trabajamos revisando colas no nos tocó ni un centavo. Si eso no es explotación, digamente que nombre tiene

Answer (score 1):

Recordé esta vieja pregunta y, releyendo tu planteamiento desde mi nueva perspectiva. La respuesta es no, no voy a apoyar de ninguna forma la "moderación" de este sitio (esta decisión la tome hace medio año).
Si, me estresaba antes, pero por que no entendía las reglas. Creía que yo era el problema, pero no... casi todos viven en una ilusión de reglas claras y estrictas cuando:

- el centro de ayuda no refleja la realidad
- hay excepciones a las normas escritas en meta
- El voto negativo es casi regalado, cuando debería ser el ultimo recurso (y sospecho que esto ultimo pasa también en el sitio en inglés, debido a una experiencia reciente)

Cito la propia publicación en cuestión, y lo aplico a los puntos anteriores

> Esto claramente repercute en nuestra métrica de preguntas respondidas

También se menciona:

> Con un par de minutos diarios haréis una gran diferencia.

Por supuesto, si sigo sus "reglas" casi arbitrarias, voy a aportar negativamente a la reputación de este sitio en internet y desorientar a los usuarios más nuevos aportando a la confusión en la moderación.

No están solos, meta51 y Stack Overflow (en inglés) también tiene algunos problemas en su moderación. Pero aquí están disparados.

En lugar de favorecer los votos de cierre, deberíamos aclarar las reglas, ya que, como dije antes, eso aportaría a menor cantidad de preguntas de baja calidad.

Comment: Tristemente debo darte la razón: ya pasó el momento de creatividad y efervescencia del sitio, que es cuando esto debía ponerse en marcha. Ahora que ya está claro que SO no va a poner más medios, poca opción nos queda. Yo hace tiempo que tampoco modero.

Answer (score -1):

Revisando los votos de cierre me encontré con esta pregunta:

[¿Por qué en ciertos lenguajes de programación el primer índice de las colecciones de datos es el 1?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/308568/por-qu%c3%a9-en-ciertos-lenguajes-de-programaci%c3%b3n-el-primer-%c3%adndice-de-las-coleccione)

La leí, y pensaba **votar en contra del cierre** porque es un tema interesante y recurrente en principios de lenguajes de programación, pero aunque no había nada de malo formalmente en la pregunta, la autorespuesta me pareció conocida. Me pareció que se basaba en una respuesta del 2017 en

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/110804/why-are-zero-based-arrays-the-norm#answer-110832

Y por un tema de opinión personal, me dije: "Ok, en realidad si no se cita aquella respuesta que me parece inspira esta, y ya que dedico unos minutos al día en emplear mi criterio para estos votos, según mi criterio sí debiera cerrarse".

Acto seguido el sistema me dijo "Caramba, no estabas prestando atención". Me pone una advertencia o amonestación o como quieran llamarle, y me deja un botón "Entendido".

Francamente, el hecho de colaborar aquí me significa un costo de oportunidad que pago feliz porque vivo y respiro software. Pero si por eso me gano a un script diciéndome que esa colaboración la hago con descuido... de qué estamos hablando?

Comment: Te encontraste con una [auditoría de revisión](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3727/83).

Comment: Nunca me tocó ese mensaje, qué bueno que ahora sabemos lo que dice en caso de fallar. Yo siempre miro, si añaden texto que no encaja con el contenido de la publicación, entonces es una prueba. Un truco es que se puede abrir la pregunta en una nueva pestaña y ver si los datos son los mismos.

Comment: A mí me parece bien que haya auditorías y que se compruebe que la gente presta atención. La pregunta que comentas fue muy bien recibida, no es copia de ninguna y, además, la atribución de contenido no es una cosa que las auditorías revisen. En cualquier caso, si hubiera sido copia de una pregunta en otro sitio, considero que la acción a realizar sería editarla para indicar la referencia.

Comment: Entiendo el sentido de la auditoría. Sencillamente pienso que está pensada para evitar casos que no se corresponden con lo que me tocó a mí. Yo siempre me paro tratando de no involucrar ideas preconcebidas, para lo cual no debo tomar en cuenta el puntaje ni la reputación de quien pregunta o quien responde. Ahora veo que el sistema sí considera esos aspectos y en realidad yo estaba mal pensando que se me planteaba una disyuntiva difícil, porque el primer impulso sería votar en contra u omitir. Tendré en cuenta el criterio de la auditoría de aquí en adelante.