# Reduzcamos a 3 el número de votos necesarios para cerrar y reabrir preguntas

Tags: discusión, estado-planificado, votos-de-cierre, votos-de-reapertura

Hoy he descubierto con sorpresa que en Stack Overflow se ha reducido el número de votos necesarios para cerrar una pregunta a 3. [Aquí tenéis el anuncio oficial](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391832):

> We’re lowering the close/reopen vote threshold on Stack Overflow from 5 to 3.
>
> About a month ago, Shog shared the results of our experiment testing this lower close/reopen threshold. From that, we observed that closing, reopening, and editing all became more efficient, so we deemed the test to be successful.

---

> Hemos bajado el límite de votos para cerrar/reabrir en Stack Overflow de 5 a 3.
>
> Hace más o menos un mes, Shog compartió los resultados de nuestro experimento probando este límite más bajo de cierre/reapertura. De ello observamos que cerrar, reabrir y editar se volvió mas eficiente, así que consideramos la prueba como un éxito.

Inmediatamente he pensado que esto para comunidades más pequeñas como la nuestra sería algo excelente. Precisamente uno de los problemas que tenemos y que ya se ha [señalado con anterioridad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4458) son las colas de cierre. Tenemos probablemente cientos de preguntas con 3 o 4 votos de cierre que quedan permanentemente en el limbo, y bajar el número de votos necesarios para su cierre y reapertura ayudaría muchísimo a solucionar este problema.

Esta publicación es un paso previo a poder solicitar que esto se implemente aquí (parece que [según comenta Shog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391832/we-re-lowering-the-close-reopen-vote-threshold-from-5-to-3-for-good#comment743117_391832), es posible conseguirlo). Para ello considero que debe existir un consenso más o menos amplio, así que es importante que expongáis vuestra opinión.

---

### Información para poner en contexto:

Durante septiembre y octubre: Nº de preguntas reportadas para cierre:1694 - 68% cerradas - 9% se votaron para permanecer abiertas - Se manejaron el 77% - lo que nos deja con un 23% que quedan en el limbo (unas 390 preguntas).

Para el mismo periodo anterior, los moderadores cerramos 529 y el resto de usuarios 1313

Comment: ¡Buena iniciativa! [En Spanish.SE lo hemos pedido también](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3260/1674)

Comment: ¿Entiendo que la propuesta es para también reducir los votos para reabrir? Lo he puesto en el título, pero si me he colado lo retiro!

Comment: @fedorqui de hecho, si no me equivoco van unidos. Si se cambia el numero de votos para cerrar, los votos de reapertura tienen que ser los mismos

Comment: ah mira eso no lo sabía, pero tiene mucho sentido

Comment: Tiene todo el sentido

Comment: ¿Qué pasaría si una pregunta tiene 4 votos? ¿En el código fuente del sitio se hace x==3 o x>=3? ¿y cuando cambia a 5 nunca llega a 3 y nunca se cerraría?

Comment: @ArtEze mmm, la publicación señala que se bajo el umbral por lo que la expresión que deben estar usando debe ser algo como: `umbral = 3` `if numero_de_votos_de_cierre >= umbral: cerrar_la_pregunta()`

Comment: Increíble [este dato](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4687): `"Of the 177 questions closed in July, 169 were closed with the help of a moderator and only eight were closed by users alone. The median number of votes needed to close a question is four"`. Muy buena la propuesta, tengo varios reportes vencidos porque nadie los revisó a tiempo, o no fueron suficientes los usuarios que los vieron. Además, me parece la mejor forma de mantener el sitio limpio, es lo que nos diferencia de foros y demás sitios Q&A

Comment: Bueeeno, parece que SO.es será de los sitios en que se pruebe esto a partir del 6 de mayo y durante 45 días. Buenas noticias. En Meta.SE, [Testing three-vote close and reopen on 12 network sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364007/209901)

Comment: Por lo pronto, ya se ha duplicado el porcentaje de cierre. En [los dos últimos días](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last2days) estamos en 28%, cuando en los últimos 90 estábamos en 13%.

Answer (score 13):

Como algunos de vosotros habéis notado en el post de Meta Stack Exchange - [Testing three-vote close and reopen on 13 network sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364007/testing-three-vote-close-and-reopen-on-13-network-sites) (está enlazado en la barra lateral de Destacado en Meta) - finalmente hemos puesto en marcha este proyecto y Stack Overflow en Español es uno de los sitios en los que haremos la prueba.

A partir de las 18 h UTC de día 6 de mayo de 2021, cambiaré la configuración del sitio y el cierre y la reapertura sólo requerirán tres votos. Esta prueba se llevará a cabo durante 45 días y se volverá a cambiar a cinco votos para cerrar y reabrir mientras reviso los datos de los 13 sitios. Después de ver el impacto, publicaré los resultados y, si no hay impactos negativos, cambiaremos la configuración a tres de forma permanente.

Dentro de unas semanas, publicaré una pregunta aquí en SO.es meta para pediros vuestra opinión sobre este cambio, de modo que tendréis la oportunidad de debatir el impacto.

Muchas gracias por vuestra paciencia mientras pudimos priorizar y programar esto. Hay mucha más información en el post de MSE, así que por favor revísadlo.

---

As some of you may have noticed the Meta Stack Exchange post - [Testing three-vote close and reopen on 13 network sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364007/testing-three-vote-close-and-reopen-on-13-network-sites) (it's linked in the Featured on Meta sidebar) - we've finally got this project under way and Stack Overflow en Español is one of the sites we'll be running the test on.

Starting tomorrow, I'll be changing the site setting and closing and reopening will require only three votes. This test will run for 45 days and will be turned back to five votes to close and reopen while I review the data from the 13 sites. After we've seen the impact, I'll be posting results and, if there aren't negative impacts, we will change the setting to three permanently.

A few weeks into this, I'll be posting a question here on SO.es meta to ask for your thoughts about this change, so you will have an opportunity to discuss the impact.

Thank you so much for your patience while we got this prioritized and scheduled. There's a lot more information in the MSE post, so please review it - if someone wants to post a translation of it as an answer here, I'm completely OK with that.

Comment: Thank you very much Catija. I hope this helps mantaining the site and become permanent. Expecting the results in 45 days :)

Comment: @Pikoh Gracias por la traducción, siempre apreciamos la ayuda de nuestros miembros comunitarios.

Comment: @JuanM de nada,para eso estamos

Comment: Y yo que pensé que de pronto me había vuelto sys-admin porque varias preguntas con 2 votos se cerraban luego de emitir el mío. Pero enhorabuena con el cambio, muchas preguntas quedaban con 4 votos.

Comment: mmm en mi opinion, pasara muchas veces que 2 personas esten en desacuerdo entre cerrar o no, una pregunta, entonces la 3ra persona decidira todo y tal vez se equivoque...de igual forma ¡Veamos el experimento!